# Tableau - Given longitude and latitude how can I count how many points fall under a certain zip code for New York?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to count how many subway stations each zip code in NYC has. I have the longitudes and latitudes of each station but am wondering how I can relate this to zip codes? Thank you for your help!

[Subway Stations on default map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsfPE.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need some spatial data source that contains the boundaries of each zip code, such as a ESRI shapefile, GeoJSON file, KML etc. Tableau's built-in geocoding can display zip code boundaries visually, but they are not accessible for computation (unless you find a way to hack the geocoding files that ship with Tableau)

It should not be hard to find a shapefile of zip code boundaries for NYC.

Once you have that use a spatial join with the INTERSECTS operator to combine the zip code boundary data with your subway station data. If your station data is not in a spatial format, you'll need to use the MAKEPOINT() function in Tableau to convert the latitude and longitude coordinates into a spatial geometry datatype that can be used to specify your join condition.

This sounds like more work that it really is. In the end, the INTERSECTS operator will do all the work to assign each station to the correct zip code.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm trying that now :)

Comment: It worked! Was able to get them both joined - kind of confused now though I have longitude on columns latitude on rows but not sure what other filters to add. I had joined my original data with the column named Geometry in the shapefile. Should I be placing that in the filters?

Comment: Depends what you want to do, but for original question, just put zip code on rows and SUM([Number of Records]) on columns, assuming you have record per station in your data

Comment: You're amazing thank you so much for your help Alex! Hope you have restful evening.

Comment: Thanks. The traditional way to express thanks on SO is to accept and upvote the answer